# Accessing a variable buried deep inside a function to use outside the function in Swift 2

Tags: json, swift, nsdateformatter

So I've run into a tiny obstacle and I'm trying to access a variable created inside an Alamofire request function. A bit of background into:

Used SwiftyJSON/Alamofire to access JSON file and parse it, have a variable for a accessing date, but date was in RFC 3339 format and now I created a function to parse the date from RFC 339 to a readable format but i don't now how to access the date variable created in the JSON parse function to use with the Date parse function.

```
//Get the JSON from server
func getJSON() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "link goes here").responseJSON { (Response) in

        if let value = Response.result.value {

            let json = JSON(value)

            for anItem in json.array! {

                let title: String? = anItem["Title"].stringValue
                let date: String? = anItem["Date"].stringValue //trying to access this variable outside the function
                let body: String? = anItem["Body"].stringValue
                self.tableTitle.append(title!)
                self.tableDate.append(date!)
                self.tableBody.append(body!)
                print(anItem["Title"].stringValue)
                print(anItem["Date"].stringValue)

            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        }

    }

}

// this date stuff isn't being used yet, because I have no idea how...
public func dateForRFC3339DateTimeString(rfc3339DateTimeString: String) -> NSDate? {

    let enUSPOSIXLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    let rfc3339DateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    rfc3339DateFormatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale
    rfc3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
    rfc3339DateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

    return rfc3339DateFormatter.dateFromString(rfc3339DateTimeString)
}

public func userVisibleDateTimeStringForRFC3339DateTimeString(rfc3339DateTimeString: String) -> String? {

    let maybeDate = dateForRFC3339DateTimeString(rfc3339DateTimeString)
    if let date = maybeDate {

        let userVisibleDateFromatter = NSDateFormatter()
        userVisibleDateFromatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        userVisibleDateFromatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

        return userVisibleDateFromatter.stringFromDate(date)

    } else {

        return nil

    }

}

let finalDateStr = userVisibleDateTimeStringForRFC3339DateTimeString(MasterViewController) //now this is where it gets weird, instead of letting me enter the string in the brackets, it defaults to MasterViewController, now I tried to move the date functions to another .swift file (an empty one) and it doesn't do that anymore
```

So yeah, that's about it, if anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use: `let convertedDate = dateForRFC3339DateTimeString(rfc3339DateTimeString: anItem["Date"].stringValue)` instead of `let date: String? = anItem["Date"].stringValue`

Comment: @Santosh Tried that, gave me a "cannot convert value of type 'NSDate' to type 'String?'. So I removed it and now it gives me 'Cannot subscript a value type 'JSON' with an index of type 'String''

Comment: Try just `anItem["Date"]` and you need to modify your method to accept `NSDate` as parameter type and modify the definition inside accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, let me know if it works:

```
func dateForRFC3339Date(rfc3339Date: NSDate) -> NSDate? {
        let enUSPOSIXLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        let rfc3339DateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        rfc3339DateFormatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale
        rfc3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
        rfc3339DateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
        let dateString = rfc3339DateFormatter.stringFromDate(rfc3339Date)
        return rfc3339DateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
    }
```

And call it in your `getJSON()` method like:

`let convertedDate = self.dateForRFC3339Date(rfc3339Date: anItem["Date"])`

Comment: it gives me the same error "Cannot subscript a value type 'JSON' with an index of type 'String'". But I did some searching and it looks like there is a way of doing it with SwiftyJSON. I'll try that and see what happens